# Angular Dynamic form

Tags: angular

I do not understand what is happening. 
First I am entered 1111 to 5555 number. **Total 5 records** then I have **delete 3333 numbe**r record after that I have **clicked on Add Target button** It show me https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e4dc.png **where 5555 record gone** but it exist in targetModel. When I debug the variable `{{targetModel | json }}`.

> Add the few records then delete from middle record then click on add
>   button. It show different result.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<form #addTargetForm="ngForm">
    <div class="row flex-baseline clerafix" *ngFor="let target of targetModel;let i=index">
        <div class="input-field caseOneL">
            <div class="target_fields">
                <span class="icon_target"></span>
                <input  maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter target name here" 
                        name="name_{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="target.Name" required>
                <span *ngIf="i>0" style="color:black" 
                      (click)="removeTarget1(i)">remove</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <button class="btn sm mat-btn-custom w_icon btn-outline" 
                 (click)="addTarget1()" >
            <span class="icon_mat left">
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </span>Add Target
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS:

```
    targetModel: any;

    constructor() {
            this.targetModel=[{Name:""}];
    }

    addTarget1() {
          let target={Name:""};
          this.targetModel.push(target);
    }

    removeTarget1(target) {
          this.targetModel.splice(target, 1)
    }
```

> ScreenShots

ScreenShot1 :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP1QF.png

ScreenShot2 :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIUcQ.png

ScreenShot3 :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e4dc.png

Comment: Can you put your code in stackblitz? It would be easier to help you

Comment: https://angular-hwtdv3.stackblitz.io